# What to call the characters-based decoration found in many announce emails

Tags: words, computing, word-requests, email, typesetting

Many emails received from Japanese companies contain characters-based [dingbat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dingbat)-style ornament like this:

```
■□■□■□────────────────────────────  
blablablablablablablabla  
────────────────────────────■□■□■□

■blabla  
｜　bla：blablabla  
｜　bla：blabla

■┓　　bla 　　┏■  
┗┛━━━━━━━━━━┗┛  
...
```

It seems to be a particular case of [Shift_JIS art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS_art) (which I don't know how to say in Japanese either, by the way).

What do you call this type of email decoration in Japanese?

Comment: According to this [page](http://www.ryucom.ne.jp/users/b/asciiart.htm) Shift_JIS art is called "JISアート"...

Comment: I think a lot of people refer to JIS / Shift_JIS / Unicode (etc.) art as "AA", ignoring whether or not it's actually ASCII.

Comment: If these are signatures (decorated or not), we just call them as "署名". It these are in bodies, these are probably called "飾り罫", I think.

Comment: @snailboat: A lot of people also call art containing non-Shift_JIS characters as Shift_JIS art. The web is already Unicode, why not our terms? ;)

Comment: Incidentally, if you google JISアート, you will get a lot of sites apparently about the difference between ASCII Art and Shift-JIS Art...

Comment: Decorative borders like this are sometimes called 境界線 (boundary lines)

Comment: @ちょこれーと that page contains many many errors, do not trust it. For example, 'JISコード(shift-JIS又はEUC-JP)は' is not correct.

Comment: 飾り罫 (decorative frame of text) is read as かざりけい.  It does not necessarily mean decorative frame _represented as_ text.  Probably there is no word which exactly describes decorative frame represented as text (either in Japanese or in English), if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This decorative frame can be called [飾り罫](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E9%A3%BE%E3%82%8A%E7%BD%AB&hl=en&tbm=isch) (かざりけい).

飾り罫 can be text-based or not, it means any kind of [dingbat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dingbat)-style framing in general.